# Windows phone 8 update tile content on flip

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

As per the documentation on Tiles, the tile flips at random intervals. So we have no control over it.

I would like to update the content of the tile only when it flips, irrespective of whenever it happens. Is there any listener which will let me know when a tile flips??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this. You can update your tile from within your app, when it is launched by the user or from a Background Agent, every 30 minutes. But you can't change tile content when it flips.